# Implement an identifier for a class or use dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

My question relates to [What's the point of IsA() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128113/whats-the-point-of-isa-in-c/4128212#4128212). I have a performance critical code that contains at a certain spot treatment of specific functions from derived classes, where only the base pointer is available. What is the best way of checking which derived class we have? I have coded up two options, in the second option I could eliminate the `Animal_type` enum and the `get_type()` function.

```
#include <iostream>

enum Animal_type { Dog_type, Cat_type };

struct Animal
{
    virtual Animal_type get_type() const = 0;
};

struct Dog : Animal
{
    void go_for_walk() const { std::cout << "Walking. Woof!" << std::endl; }
    Animal_type get_type() const { return Dog_type; }
};

struct Cat : Animal
{
    void be_evil() const { std::cout << "Being evil!" << std::endl; }
    Animal_type get_type() const { return Cat_type; }
};

void action_option1(Animal* animal)
{
    if (animal->get_type() == Dog_type)
        dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animal)->go_for_walk();
    else if (animal->get_type() == Cat_type)
        dynamic_cast<Cat*>(animal)->be_evil();
    else
        return;
}

void action_option2(Animal* animal)
{
    Dog* dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animal);
    if (dog)
    {
        dog->go_for_walk();
        return;
    }

    Cat* cat = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(animal);
    if (cat)
    {
        cat->be_evil();
        return;
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    Animal* cat = new Cat();
    Animal* dog = new Dog();

    action_option1(cat);
    action_option2(cat);

    action_option1(dog);
    action_option2(dog);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you measured the performance of both approaches?

Comment: Why not use good old dynamic dispatch with virtual functions? Also, type-switching usually is considered a huge code-smell. Did you consider a Visitor, Strategy or Template Method?

Comment: why not have action_option1 and action_option2 as virtual's on Animal and have them call the go_for_walk/be_evil?

Comment: @TartanLlama I have not measured it yet, I took the easy approach to ask the experts here, as this has probably been tested by other people before.

Comment: @Jens. I have considered several options. Our code has the option of running in basic and more advanced mode, and in case of the advanced mode it asks the derived class for extra information that is not available in the basic mode. Which type of pattern do you associate with something like that?

Comment: @Chiel Usually the one I mentioned. The point is to factor out the different behavior in its own abstraction. I would also add Decorator to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It largely depends on *how* performance-critical your performance-critical code is. I've seen setups where even dynamic dispatch of virtual functions was too costly, so if you're in such territory, forget about `dynamic_cast` and hand-craft something.

I will assume you're fine with a virtual call or two, though. You will probably want to steer clear of `dynamic_cast`, as that is usually much slower than a dynamic dispatch.

Right now, you have *N* classes derived from the common base and *M* points in code where you need to take a decision based on the concrete derived class. The question is: which of *N, M* is more likely to change in the future? Are you more likely to add new derived classes, or introduce new points where type-decision matters? This answer will determine the best design for you.

If you're going to add new classes, but the number of type-discriminating places is fixed (and ideally small as well), the enumeration approach would be the best choice. Just use a `static_cast` instead of a `dynamic_cast`; if you *know* the actual runtime type, you don't need to access RTTI to do the conversion for you (unless virtual bases and a deeper inheritance hierarchy are involved).

On the other hand, if the list classes is fixed, but new type-discriminating operations are likely to be introduced (or if there's simply too many of them to maintain), consider the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) instead. Give your `Animal` class a virtual visitor-accepting function:

```
virtual void accept(AnimalVisitor &v) = 0;

struct AnimalVisitor
{
  virtual void visit(Dog &dog) = 0;
  virtual void visit(Cat &cat) = 0;
};
```

Then, each derived class will implement it:

```
void Dog::accept(AnimalVisitor &v)
{
  v.visit(*this);
}

void Cat::accept(AnimalVisitor &v)
{
  v.visit(*this);
}
```

And your operations will just use it:

```
void action(Animal *animal)
{
  struct Action : AnimalVisitor
  {
    void visit(Dog &d) override { d.go_for_walk(); }
    void visit(Cat &c) override { c.be_evil(); }
  };

  AnimalVisitor v;

  animal->accept(v);
}
```

If you're going to be adding both new derived classes and new operations, you can add non-abstract functions to the above visitor so that existing code which doesn't need to know about the new classes does not break:

```
struct AnimalVisitor
{
  virtual void visit(Dog &d) = 0;
  virtual void visit(Cat &c) = 0;
  virtual void visit(Parrot &p) {}
};
```

Comment: Have you measured if there really is a difference between virtual dispatch and using a type-tag? Dynamic dispatch is just one indirection, and the type-tag needs a branch. I remember an old paper about dynamic dispatch implementations in a JVM, and there it really depended on the number of sub-classes, the actual type distribution (if you take the same branch every time branch prediction will be good, if you have different types every time it will make you suffer) and of course the hardware.

Comment: @Jens No, I haven't done any measurements. I omitted making `action` a virtual function in the class for two reasons: 1), your answer covers it; 2), it pollutes the class with something which can potentially be external to it. Yes, there are indeed cases where making it a virtual function is appropriate; but I sort of assumed the OP was aware of this possibility. However, both solution I propose require only generic support from the class, nothing `action`-specific.

Answer (score 2):

I want to quote the accepted answer to the question you are citing:

> In modern C++ there is no point.

For your example, the easiest solution is to use dynamic dispatch:

```
struct Animal {
    virtual void action() = 0;
};

struct Dog{
    virtual void action()  { std::cout << "Walking. Woof!" << std::endl; }
};

struct Animal {
    virtual void action()  { std::cout << "Being evil!" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Animals* a[2] = {new Cat(), new Dog()};
    a[0]->action();
    a[1]->action();
    delete a[0];
    delete a[1];
    return 0;
 }
```

For more complex scenarios, you may consider design patterns such as Strategy, Template Method or Visitor.

If this really is a performance bottlenect, it may help to declare `Dog` and `Cat` as `final`.

Comment: What do you mean with declaring as final? And what does this do?

Comment: @Chiel A class declared as [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) cannot be derived from.

Comment: @Angew and does that make a dynamic cast much faster?

Comment: @Chiel No idea about `dynamic_cast`. It could make dynamic dispatch faster, by giving the compiler more room to optimise. As soon as it can figure our that the dynamic type of an object is *at least* a `Dog`, it will know it must be *exactly* `Dog`, and hence does not need to issue dynamic dispatch for a virtual function call.

Comment: @Chiel Declaring it as final can improve the dynamic dispatch. Basically, it helps the compiler to determine statically which class is actually used, and do a static dispatch.

Comment: @Angew The dynamic_cast is probably slower than a virtual method call. I don't think you win anything here.

Comment: @Jens Hm, it seems my comment might be ambiguous. I meant "I have no idea whether `final` can make `dynamic_cast` faster. But `final` could make dynamic dispatch faster, by ..." IOW, the "it" was referring to `final`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first option will be faster, but only if you fix the erroneous `dynamic_cast` (it should be `static_cast`):

```
void action_option1_fixed(Animal* animal)
{
    if (animal->get_type() == Dog_type)
        static_cast<Dog*>(animal)->go_for_walk();
    else if (animal->get_type() == Cat_type)
        static_cast<Cat*>(animal)->be_evil();
}
```

The point of using manual dispatch on `get_type()` here is that it allows you to *avoid* the expensive call to `__dynamic_cast` in the C++ runtime. As soon as you've made that call into the runtime, you lose.

If you use the `final` qualifier on both `Dog` and `Cat` (that is, on every class in your program that you know will never have child classes), then *you* will have enough information to know that

```
dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animal)
```

can be implemented as a simple pointer comparison; but sadly (as of 2017) neither GCC nor Clang implements such an optimization. You can do the optimization by hand, without introducing a `get_type` method, by using the C++ `typeid` operator:

```
void action_option3(Animal* animal)
{
    static_assert(std::is_final_v<Dog> && std::is_final_v<Cat>, "");
    if (typeid(*animal) == typeid(Dog))
        static_cast<Dog*>(animal)->go_for_walk();
    else if (typeid(*animal) == typeid(Cat))
        static_cast<Cat*>(animal)->be_evil();
}
```

Compiling with `clang++ -std=c++14 -O3 -S` should show you the benefits of the third approach here.

`action_option1` starts off with

```
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    movq    (%rbx), %rax
    callq   *(%rax)
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    jne     LBB0_1
    movq    __ZTI6Animal@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    movq    __ZTI3Dog@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdx
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   ___dynamic_cast
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    jmp     __ZNK3Dog11go_for_walkEv ## TAILCALL
```

`action_option1_fixed` improves it to

```
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    movq    (%rbx), %rax
    callq   *(%rax)
    cmpl    $1, %eax
    jne     LBB2_1
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    jmp     __ZNK3Dog11go_for_walkEv ## TAILCALL
```

(notice that in the fixed version, the call to `__dynamic_cast` is gone, replaced by just a little pointer math).

`action_option2` is actually shorter than `action_option1` because it doesn't add a virtual call *on top of* the `__dynamic_cast`, but it's still awful:

```
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
    testq   %rbx, %rbx
    je      LBB1_3
    movq    __ZTI6Animal@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    movq    __ZTI3Dog@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rdx
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   ___dynamic_cast
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je      LBB1_2
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    jmp     __ZNK3Dog11go_for_walkEv ## TAILCALL
```

And here's `action_option3`. It's small enough that I can just paste the entire function definition here, instead of excerpting:

```
__Z14action_option3P6Animal:
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    je      LBB3_4
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movq    -8(%rax), %rax
    movq    8(%rax), %rax
    cmpq    __ZTS3Dog@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    je      LBB3_5
    cmpq    __ZTS3Cat@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    je      LBB3_6
    retq
LBB3_5:
    jmp     __ZNK3Dog11go_for_walkEv ## TAILCALL
LBB3_6:
    jmp     __ZNK3Cat7be_evilEv     ## TAILCALL
LBB3_4:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    callq   ___cxa_bad_typeid
```

The `__cxa_bad_typeid` cruft at the end is because it might be the case that `animal == nullptr`. You can eliminate that cruft by making your parameter of type `Animal&` instead of `Animal*`, so that the compiler knows it's non-null.

I tried adding this line at the top of the function:

```
if (animal == nullptr) __builtin_unreachable();
```

but sadly, Clang's implementation of `typeid` didn't pick up on that hint.